# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes when connecting to iphone 6s usb tethering

Tags: 16.04, usb, iphone

So my recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 freezes a lot and after watching `/var/log/syslog` around that time it happens with this error getting logged mulitple times with every freeze   .

```
Mar 30 16:59:29 hp usbmuxd[800]: [16:59:29.047][1] config_get_device_record: failed to read '/var/lib/lockdown/bfcfa14a390c245aed13cbdbd27ccce3cc865eb5.plist': No such file or directory
```

Checking that file out it mentions Apple, more evidence is the fact that I ran Ubuntu flawlessly for the past 5 days for hours and hours without iPhone being connected via USB. So do we have any fix for this ? My device is a HP notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a driver or memory thing

Driver fix:
`$ sudo do-release-update`
That will update the Ubuntu version to 18.10
If that doesn't fix it update the kernel.
`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa`
`$ sudo apt update`
`$ sudo apt install ukuu`
Find ukuu in the start menu once it installs
Open it, select Linux 5.0.5, press install, and once it's installed reboot.

Memory fix:
In your bios (what pops up when you start up), mash f keys until you get to select a partition (usually F1 or F4).
Under Ubuntu [version] it should say mem test.
Select that, press enter, and wait for it to pass or fail the test 2-4 times (that may take a while) 
If it fails, buy new RAM.
*Buying ram:* *In Canada use Canada Computers, in the us use Amazon/Newegg*
If neither of these work, respond please!